# Unable to activate VPN since last update

Tags: 14.04, vpn

I have a custom VPN endpoint set up on Ubuntu using Point-to-Point protocol. This has worked fine for the last few months, but since updating Ubuntu (14.04) today, the connection does not work at all.

In fact, selecting my VPN connection (Network Icon on notification bar -> VPN Connections -> ConnectionName), nothing that I can see happens at all.

Is the output logged somewhere? Or is there somewhere else that I can see if anything is even being triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed all connections from `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`, then rebooted, set up my connections again, and everything works